# Is it possible to inadvertently dispute your own flag while performing a review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-flags

While performing a [review session for a first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7850201), I followed the link to read the full question and other answer, and upon re-reading the answer I noticed that it essentially said "this should work.. but I have a problem too" - so I flagged the post as "not an answer."

I noticed that the flag was subsequently disputed and decided to take a look at what actions the other reviewers had taken.

On my action history, the first thing I noticed was that the post was annotated as "Reviewed" rather than "Not an Answer."  I noticed that all my other reviews that I had flagged showed the reason for the flag, but this one did not.

Also, most of the time when I look at a review it shows the other users that reviewed and what action they took, but on this review it seems I am the only user.

My best guess based on the information I have available is that I may have flagged the post from my secondary browser tab, and then returned to the first tab and clicked "I'm Done."

Because I don't see any evidence of any other reviewers, I'm wondering whether I effectively disputed my own flag - or if there is some other information available that I am not noticing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between your First Post review and the review task that you created by flagging that post. When you flag a post as Not an answer, a new review task is created in the Low Quality review queue (for 2k+ rep users).

There is no way to find that review task which you created from the flagging history. When you reach 10k, you will be able to see the history of all previous reviews. I found it and it was [unanimous](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7850472). I'm not sure how I would have reviewed it.

After the weekly data dump was created, you will also be able to find all review tasks using [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/203969/find-the-reviewtasks-for-a-post).

So, to answer your question, you didn't dispute your own flag and this is not possible apart from some bugs in the Triage review queue.

Comment: If your reviewing flags, is it not possible to see your own content. Probably highly unlikely, but is you not seeing your own stuff actually coded into the queue?

Comment: @CalvinSmith I'm assuming that you mean by content any questions or answers from yourself. No, probably not. I haven't seen this, and I would think this is quite strange if you could review your own posts, because there's room for abuse there.